# How to only expose part of prima generated schema in nestjs

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to integrate nestjs with prisma. I followed the [tutorial](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/prisma) in nestjs document.

Everthing works fine until I want to make some changes so nestjs doesn't expose all the query/mutations schema.

what I did is
1. update app module not let typePath include the generated schema

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from 'app/app.controller';
import { AppService } from 'app/app.service';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      typePaths: ['./src/**/*.schema.graphql'],
      debug: true,
      playground: true,
    }),
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

2. Then I created a `user.schema.graphql` file in `user` folder:

```
#import User from "../prisma/generated/prisma.graphql"

type Query {
  user(id: ID!): User
}
```

However, I got some error saying I can't import User:

```
(node:36277) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Type "User" not found in document.
    at ASTDefinitionBuilder._resolveType (/Users/anx/Projects/axesk/gallery-api/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:100:11)
    at ASTDefinitionBuilder.buildType (/Users/anx/Projects/axesk/gallery-api/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:210:79)
    at ASTDefinitionBuilder._buildWrappedType (/Users/anx/Projects/axesk/gallery-api/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:229:17)
    at ASTDefinitionBuilder.buildField (/Users/anx/Projects/axesk/gallery-api/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:249:18)
    at /Users/anx/Projects/axesk/gallery-api/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:332:21
    at /Users/anx/Projects/axesk/gallery-api/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/keyValMap.js:36:31
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at keyValMap (/Users/anx/Projects/axesk/gallery-api/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/keyValMap.js:35:15)
    at ASTDefinitionBuilder._makeFieldDefMap (/Users/anx/Projects/axesk/gallery-api/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:329:48)
    at fields (/Users/anx/Projects/axesk/gallery-api/node_modules/graphql/utilities/buildASTSchema.js:312:22)
(node:36277) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:36277) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm new to nestjs and graphql, please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I make it work in sort of hack way.. i will just paste my solution here for anyone who got same problem.

For example i have a `user.schema.graphql` that import some type from `prisma.graphql`:

```
#import User from "../prisma/generated/prisma.graphql"

type Query {
  user(id: ID!): User
}
```

Then i create a `main.schema.graphql` file that will import every schemas from the project manually.

```
#import * from "./user/user.schema.graphql"
```

Finally just import this maim schema to `app.module.ts`:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from 'app/app.controller';
import { AppService } from 'app/app.service';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
import { importSchema } from 'graphql-import';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      resolverValidationOptions: {
        requireResolversForResolveType: false,
      },
      typeDefs: importSchema('./src/main.schema.graphql'),
      debug: true,
      playground: true,
    }),
    UserModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Doing this not really ideal. if graphql-import library can import from folders, it makes life easier.

or the @nest/graphql library can use graphql-import instead of merge-graphql-schemas under the hood to build typeDefs will be also great.